# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ...\python.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

De un momento a otro tengo problemas para usar un entorno virtual con **python 3.9 x32 Bits**, me da el error descrito en el título.

El entorno se activa correctamente, pero al ingresar cualquier comando, `pip freeze` por ejemplo, me arroja dicho error.

¿Qué podría ser?

Tengo 2 versiones de Python, la 3.9 pero de 32 y 64 bits, la que tengo por defecto en el "PATH" es la de 64, y la de 32 la uso desde el entorno virtual. Funcionaba bien pero luego de algunas limpiezas al pc dejó de funcionar.

He reinstalado las dos versiones y nada, ¿Qué podría haber pasado? ¿El error será en los archivos del entorno virtual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya tengo la respuesta, el problema es que mi carpeta de usuario del sistema tiene un espacio (Pedro Torcatt), y al parecer eso causa conflicto con **Virtualenv**, la única solución que vi en la web es cambiar el nombre de dicha carpeta a uno sin espacio, pero tengo entendido que esto podría causar conflictos con otros programas quizás, en mi caso preferí no hacer eso y me cree un nuevo usuario de Windows con otro nombre de usuario sin espacios y problema resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo salvo que tengas una razón específica (en tu caso, módulos de Python construidos en 32 bits), utiliza la versión de 64bits ya que da menos problemas y hay muchas bibliotecas más actuales (como `Tensorflow` por ejemplo) que no funcionan en 64 bits o que dan problemas por requerimientos de memoria.

Por otro lado, tu problema suele darse cuando no está actualizado el paquete `pip` por eso te arroja el error al hacer `pip freeze`. Actualiza `pip` con el siguiente comando:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Puse pip freeze como ejemplo, pero el error se da con cualquier comando menos con "Python", que de manera correcta si da paso a la consola de Python, pero el resto de comandos no. Utilizo la version de 32 bits para compilar programas para dicha arquitectura con pyinstaller. Estuve leyendo y el problema puede ser que mi carpeta de usuario tiene un espacio en el nombre, "Pedro Torcatt", y eso causa conflicto con virtualenv, pero cambiar el nombre de dicha carpeta es mucho rollo :/